# .htaccess rewrite for Wordpress host hosted on Bitnami/EC2

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ubuntu

I installed a Bitnami Ubuntu Wordpress instance on Amazon EC2.

The `wordpress.conf` file on a Bitnami instance acts like an htaccess file.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/index.php
```

The `wordpress.conf` file contains

```
Alias /wordpress/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"
Alias /wordpress "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</Directory>

# Uncomment the following lines to see your application in the root
# of your URL. This is not compatible with more than one application.
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^/$ /wordpress/ [PT]
```

This makes the blog appear with this URL

**http://ec2instance.com/wordpress/**

I would like it to be (including when viewing individual posts):

**http://ec2instance.com/blog/**

**http://ec2instance.com/blog/post-number-1**

**http://ec2instance.com/blog/post-number-2**

etc

Anyone know how to make this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that file you will need to change:

```
Alias /wordpress/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"
Alias /wordpress "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
```

to

```
Alias /blog/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"
Alias /blog "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
```

With that change apache will serve wordpress in `/blog`.

Then you need to change the rewrite rules also in that file (because the new urls will use `/blog` instead of `/wordpress`).

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

Finally you will need to modify also the `wp-config.php` file (in `apps/wordpress/htdocs`) making sure that the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` urls points to `/blog`.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog');
```