# Redirect Wordpress homepage to subpage

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have created a Wordpress directory within an AWS EC2 instance.  I would like to redirect just the homepage www.website.com to www.website.com/landing without breaking the rest of the site.

I've tried the answers to many similar questions within stackflow but cannot seem to get it to work properly.

I have attempted editing the .htaccess file within bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs.  The current .htaccess code is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

As stated, I've tried many other suggestions without success.  Should I be making changes to a different .htaccess file?  Have I just not used the proper rule?  If so, what is the proper rule?

I apologize for my ignorance here, thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `^$` matches the root of a host.
Try adding this to the top of your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /landing [R,L]
```

Comment: I've added your suggestion to the file but it doesn't do the trick unfortunately:

'RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /landing

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress'

Comment: Forgot the `[R,L]`, try that.  It works when I input and test on http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: Still not working, should I be rebooting the ubuntu server after making the change?  I'm making these edits within the terminal

Comment: You shouldn't need to reboot.  Doing a quick google search on bitnami wordpress got me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163270/htaccess-rewrite-for-wordpress-host-hosted-on-bitnami-ec2, it may be more helpful since it looks like doing this on that setup is a little different than most.

Comment: I put the code into htaccess.mwl.be and am getting an output at:

:80/index.php

Along with the following debugging info:

1 RewriteRule ^$ /landing/ [R=301,L] This rule was not met.
2 RewriteBase / Using / as the base for the rewrites.
3 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] This rule was not met.
4 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f This condition was met.
5 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d This condition was met.
6 RewriteRule . /index.php [L] The new url is :80/index.php
The tests are stopped because of the L in your RewriteRule options.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is because you're doing /index.php which is not the root of the site.  Are you just trying to set your front page?  That is done in the wordpress GUI under Reading.

Comment: That wasn't the original intent but now that you bring it up I can create a solution that way.  Thanks for your time and input @GentlemanMax!